# Node: Correct way of waiting for a Post request to finish and handle the callback

Tags: node.js, http, callback, request, cucumberjs

So I've been trying to implement a Cucumber step that does a POST request to a website, waits for the request to finish ( because following steps rely on post being successful) and break the test if anything went awry:

```
this.Then(/^Post file "([^"]*)" and wait for the request to finish$/, function(fileName, callback) {

  var request = require("request");
  var fs = require("fs-extra");

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://www.testOver9000.com/",
    body: fs.readJsonSync(fileName),
    json: true,
    auth: {
      username: "test",
      password: "test"
    }
  };

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      callback(null);
    } else {
      callback(error);
    }
  });
});
```

At the moment I'm having two issues here:

1. This step doesn't wait for the HTTP POST to finish, before moving to the next step.
2. If the request fails, the error is not passed back into the callback and doesn't flag it failed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what version of cucumberjs? Have you printing `error`

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that your test is failing before even POST call is triggered. If the below line fails, I don't know if cucumber is silently failing and going to next step.

```
body: fs.readJsonSync(fileName)
```

Are you printing error? what version of cucumberjs? These answers could help you guide better